# When I call driver.find_elements_by_class_name('radio') why size don't want show?

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

When I try scrape this link

```
https://hbx.com/brands/reebok/club-c-85-1
```

When I call use

```
driver.find_elements_by_class_name('radio') or driver.find_elements_by_class_name('hidden-xs') or driver.find_elements_by_class_name('form-control')
```

Why I can't see the size number? What I got is this.

```
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d8112720343cc58b0a17512f8cd83c7a", element="0.3067735208506053-494")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d8112720343cc58b0a17512f8cd83c7a", element="0.3067735208506053-495")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d8112720343cc58b0a17512f8cd83c7a", element="0.3067735208506053-496")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d8112720343cc58b0a17512f8cd83c7a", element="0.3067735208506053-497")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d8112720343cc58b0a17512f8cd83c7a", element="0.3067735208506053-498")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d8112720343cc58b0a17512f8cd83c7a", element="0.3067735208506053-499")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d8112720343cc58b0a17512f8cd83c7a", element="0.3067735208506053-500")>]
```

my script

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

#url target
driver.get("https://hbx.com/categories/sneakers")

#masuk link
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a.picture').click()

#size/color
driver.find_elements_by_class_name('radio')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**find_elements_by_class_name**: It returns the list of objects of WebElements. And not the text you are interested in.  Text is the property of WebElement (not list though)

So you could do something like this.

```
for elem in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('radio'): 
    print elem.text
```

And if there is only single element matching the given classname, you could simply do something like this .

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('radio').text
```

Comment: Hi, `driver.find_element_by_class_name('radio').text` is work! 

But when I use 
`driver.find_element_by_class_name('radio').text' or `driver.find_elements_by_class_name('radio')` i got this **Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>`
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'**

Comment: Then, why I can't use multiple elements?

Comment: because list doesn't have  the property named `text`. Please first learn the programming language concept before jumping to automation else you will stuck at each and every point. also if this answers your question, you should accept it.

Comment: I see, sorry i late to edit or add new comment. Your answer help me a lot! I change to xpath then it's work.